# Why one would pass a function to a react component to obtain the data instead of data itself?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have a question, that might be subtle (or not).

Why one would pass a function to a react component to obtain the data instead of data itself?
A short example would be

```
<CompTest data={data} ...>
```

vs

```
const getData() => data;
<CompTest data={()=> getData()} ...>
```

I am wondering if there is a trick with the react data pulling it with laziness ... not sure..

Comment: If getting the data is not something that you want to do immediately, and is something you want to allow the component to control, then it makes sense to pass a function rather than the data itself.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you just send the data down as props as in  `<CompTest data={data} />` or even better make explicit props the that you'll know what fields from the data the component uses. But that is programing preference as long as the data is immutable.

In very rare cases you will want to use functions to retrieve data.

Normally you will use functions to update data from a child to a parent componetn: `<CompTest data={data} onDataChanged={setData} />` where `setData` is a function pf type `setData(data:DataType)=>void` (TypeScript way to say argument of type DataType and return nothing)